# How do I change my canonical tag url on every page in EJS

Tags: html, node.js, ejs, meta-tags, canonical-link

So in my NodeJS app I wanted to change the canonical link for every page but the problem is that I have made a header component in EJS and used that in every page that is why if I change url from header it is changed site wide.

Comment: Facing similar issue here. Have you found any solution?

Comment: No man. I just try to change it with java script but web crawlers do not crawl java script (most)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have totally forgot I was looking for an answer. I did find a solution.

 Method for getting canonical.

```
const getCanonicalUrl = (req) => {
   return ('https://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl).replace('www.', 
            '').toLowerCase(); 
}
```

In your route description

```
   router.get(`/${route.path}`, function (req, res) {
      const canonicalURL = getCanonicalUrl(req);

      .......

      res.render(`${route.layout}`, {
        canonicalURL,
      });
   });
```

And in your `meta.ejs` template like

```
<% if (typeof canonicalURL != "undefined") { %>
  <link rel="canonical"
        href="<%= canonicalURL %>" />
<% } %>
```

Tell me if it helps!